# ios phonegap display issue with black box

Tags: ios, css, cordova

My boss just tested the cordova app we've made with phonegap. He is now on his way to the customer who uses iOS.

It looks perfectly normal on my android devices. It has worked before with the same html, css and javascript (The only things updated has been ajax url's).

What has changed? Has anyone run into problems such as this before?

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app didn't help.

[image: This is what the screen looks like]

[image: Portrait]

Comment: are you using phonegap build service to create the app? or cordova local development? do you have the statusbar plugin installed? which version?

Comment: phonegap build service, com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar is installed to make android and ios status bar look the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of the statusbar plugin, use the latest version of the plugin published on npm.
Remove the line for `com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar` and add this one

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
```